# Python function not modifying the list passed to it

Tags: python, list, parameter-passing, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value

1. Why doesn't the function `x` modify the contents of the list that is passed to it?
2. How can I change the MWE so that `x` *does* modify the contents of the list that is passed to it?

```py
>>> def x(mylist):
...     mylist = [ x for x in mylist if x > 5 ]
... 
>>> foo = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
>>> x(foo)
>>> print foo
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

Comment: `mylist =` makes `mylist` point to a different list.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The function doesn't modify `x` because it is reassigning the name `mylist` to a new value.  The alternative to this would be surprising.

```
a = 1
b = a
b = 2
assert a == 1 # would you want a to be 2 here?
```

If you want to replace the contents you can do so with a slice assignment

```
def x(mylist):
    mylist[:] = [ x for x in mylist if x > 5 ]
```

The assignment operator in python doesn't go into any method calls. It is the mechanism for name rebinding.  However, you can implement the `__setitem__` method (as `list` does), which is more or less the operator `[]=`

With slice assignment you are calling `__setitem__` with a `slice` argument that says "replace this slice of the list with ..." where ... is the right side of the `=`

Comment: I'm confused.  In Python, I thought that `a=1` creates a reference to 1, and then `b=a` creates another reference to the same 1, so that then executing `b=2` *would* in fact change the value of the object (the 1) referred to by `a`. Can you please help me see my error?

Comment: @synaptik why would you think that? Particularly with immutable objects like integers, even a trivial example would disabuse you of that.

Comment: You are correct in the first two steps but `b = 2` makes `b` reference a *different* object with the value `2` rather than modifying the `1` in memory.

Comment: When you say `b = a` you are saying "make `b` point to whatever `a` points to." When you say `b = 2` you are saying "make `b` point to `2`" not "change what `b` is already pointing to, to be `2`"

Answer (score 1):

As Ryan Haining explained, `x` is reassigning the list. It should, however, only modify the list items:

```
def x(mylist):
    for i in reversed(mylist):
        if not i > 5:
            mylist.remove(i)
```

Note that you should traverse the list in reversed order.